# Selenium is unfollowing just 12 accounts after that stops the procces

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scroll, instagram

I made a bot for instagram using selenium. This bot should unfollow the accounts that i follow. It works just for the first 12 accounts! After that it stops!
Why this happend?  i tried to use try and except ! In except i ve made a scroll function but it didn t worked!
Here s my code:

```js
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Following')]")
for btn in range(len(buttons)):
        try:
        # Use the Java script to click on follow because after the scroll down the buttons will be un clickeable unless you go to it's location
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Following')]").click()
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
            sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="aOOlW -Cab_   "]').click()
            sleep(5)
        except:
            print("Eroare")
        else:
           
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
```

Comment: What is the except message/error ? You should catch the errors so you could traceback the issues.

Comment: how to catch the error?

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-catch-and-print-exception-messages-in-python